# How to determine the current directory in a batch file

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, batch-file

How can I determine the current directory in a batch file. Other than `%~dp0`.

So that when I run the batch file from source folder (consisting of my files) it returns the path of source folder, where ever it may be.

Answer (score 3):

The environment variable `%cd%` contains the current folder:

```
H:\Downloads>type currentdir.bat
echo %cd%
H:\Downloads>currentdir.bat

H:\Downloads>echo H:\Downloads
H:\Downloads

H:\Downloads>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that batch processing may require double-%, so `%%cd%%`.

Comment: @RandolphWest, not for this case

Comment: That's good to know.